# How do I get Upload and Download usage on my Cocoa app (Xamarin.Mac) at a certain time

Tags: c#, .net, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I got two properties from [IPv4InterfaceStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics?view=xamarinmac-3.0) class, which are BytesReceived and BytesSent for getting the number of bytes that were received and sent from an interface respectively.

I'm getting all of the available network interfaces using [NetworkInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=xamarinmac-3.0) API.

`NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();`

But `ipv4Stats.BytesSent` and `_ipv4Stats.BytesReceived` always returns zero value.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CheckUsageNetwork();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private void CheckUsageNetwork()
{
    NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    IPv4InterfaceStatistics _ipv4Stats;

    foreach (var nInterface in interfaces)
    {
        try
        {
            _ipv4Stats = nInterface.GetIPv4Statistics();

            // Hidden speed calculation for brevity
            var uploadSpeed = _ipv4Stats.BytesSent;
            var downloadSpeed = _ipv4Stats.BytesReceived;

            if (uploadSpeed > 0 || downloadSpeed > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(uploadSpeed + " " + downloadSpeed);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have used the same code for my win project (WPF), it works.

Can you suggest to me how could I get network usage upload/download speeds on my Xamarin.Mac app? Any kind of help would be appreciated.